# Getting back annotations with scala macros

Tags: scala, annotations, scala-macros

I'm writing a macro that allows to "materialize" some annotations of the members of some classes, but it just makes scalac fail with assertion errors.

Here is a very simplified version of it: a macro that gives an instance of the first annotation of a given type,

```
import scala.language.experimental.macros
import scala.reflect.macros.whitebox

object FirstAnn {
  def applyImpl[T: c.WeakTypeTag, Ann: c.WeakTypeTag](c: whitebox.Context): c.Tree = {
    import c.universe._

    val tpe = weakTypeOf[T]
    val annTpe = weakTypeOf[Ann]

    val constructor = tpe.decl(termNames.CONSTRUCTOR).asMethod

    val l =
      constructor.paramLists.flatten.flatMap { sym =>
        tpe.member(sym.name).annotations.filter(_.tree.tpe =:= annTpe).map(_.tree)
      }

    l match {
      case h :: _ =>
        h
      case Nil =>
        c.abort(c.enclosingPosition, s"No $annTpe annotation found")
    }
  }

  def apply[T, Ann]: Ann = macro applyImpl[T, Ann]
}
```

Calling this macro for the following example,

```
@getter case class TestAnnotation(value: String) extends annotation.StaticAnnotation
case class Test(
  @TestAnnotation("test") member: String
)
```

from `sbt console`, like

```
FirstAnnotation[Test, TestAnnotation]
```

makes scalac fail with an assertion error, and an output that totally overflows my terminal.

So my question is: can I get annotation instances the way I'm trying to? Could this be a scalac or scala-macros bug?

Comment: Full example here: https://gist.github.com/alexarchambault/daff0a6c4b45af575085

Comment: Have you tried defining the macro in a different file?

Comment: What for? I'm already calling it from a different place (namely, sbt console). FYI, the macro definition and the method definition were already in different files in my original case, without more success.